# Prevent app exit from UIWebView link

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIWebView in my app which shows the clients webpage, however I would like to retain the user within the app if they choose to browse the webpage.

Can I prevent it breaking out to Safari when a link is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing UIWebViewDelegate's:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

HTH.

Comment: Im not sure what you are suggesting?!

Comment: You could handle this by returning FALSE, and implement your own logic.